# tracのリポジトリブラウザ上から完全にファイルを消す方法

Tags: svn

誤って必要のないファイルをsvn commitしてしまい、
tracのリポジトリブラウザ上に置かれてしまいました。

それらを完全に消す方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

tracのsvnがどうなっているのかは分かりませんが、svn上で完全に消したいのならサーバ側でsvnadminコマンドを利用して任意のrevisionまで戻してやる必要があります。
http://ftvoid.com/blog/post/113

tracの管理をご自分でやられていないのであれば、tracの管理者にご相談ください。
この方法だとバックアップやら再度リポジトリを作ったりやらで結構な作業が発生しますので...あまりオススメしません。

クライアント側からしか操作ができないのであれば、不要ファイルの削除(svn rm)を行い、再度Commitしましょう。
履歴は汚くなってしまいますが、不要ファイルがリポジトリに残っている状態はよろしくありませんので...